# Problem Telegram inlinebot with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, inline, telegram

i try create my inlinebot , but when i use one item then run correctly, but when i try add more items dinamically from sheet the bit don't show items

I use this code, for send the result array :

```
function answerInlineQuery(id, result){
  var options = {
        method: "post",
        payload: {
          method: "answerInlineQuery",
          inline_query_id: id,
          cache_time : 1 , 
          results:JSON.stringify(result)         }
}
  var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch( telegramUrl_inline + '/', options);
   Logger.log(request.getContentText());
}
```

And the script that i use for create data is :

```
var list = new Array(); 


  for(i in info)
  {
    var row = info[i];

     list.push([{'type':'photo' , 'photo_url': url_foto , "thumb_url": url_foto2 , 'id': i ,'photo_width': 100 , 'photo_height': 100 }]);    
    }

    answerInlineQuery(id, list);
```

}

I'm searching for all forums but i can't find the solution for the problem.

Thank's

Comment: Why url_foto is the same in each item? Shouldn't it be something like row['url_foto']?

Comment: It's for test, not is the problem, when i try for one item it run correctly. one url is the large foto and second yhe thumb photo but isn't the problem

Comment: So, what is the code you use to add from sheet?